# Google Cloud Functions -> Send message to Slack

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-functions, slack

I'm trying to put this on Google Cloud Functions with entry point of `send_message_to_slack`.

Currently getting this error

> 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
def send_message_to_slack(response):
    import requests

    slack_api_token = 'XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    slack_channel_id = 'XXXX'

    # Slack API URL for sending messages to a channel
    slack_api_url = f'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'

    # Payload to send to Slack API
    payload = {
        'token': slack_api_token,
        'channel': slack_channel_id,
        'text': 'Hello from Cloud Functions'
    }

    # Send POST request to Slack API
    response = requests.post(slack_api_url, data=payload)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Message sent to Slack successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to send message to Slack. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Tried splitting the function and creating a separate function underneath it. Also didn't work

Comment: Would be really useful if you could post any logs that are appearing in Cloud Logging.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem with the payload. Even though you added the `payload` variable as a `json` you can try to ass `json.dump` when you send the request.

```
def send_message_to_slack(response):
    import requests
    import json 

    slack_api_token = 'XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    slack_channel_id = 'XXXX'

    # Slack API URL for sending messages to a channel
    slack_api_url = f'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'

    # Payload to send to Slack API
    payload = {
        'token': slack_api_token,
        'channel': slack_channel_id,
        'text': 'Hello from Cloud Functions'
    }

    # Send POST request to Slack API
    response = requests.post(slack_api_url, data=json.dumps(payload))

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Message sent to Slack successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to send message to Slack. Status code:", response.status_code)
```